# How do I make this function able to use a numpy array as an argument and return an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, masking

How do I make this function able to use a numpy array as an argument and return an array of the same size in which tan() was applied element-wise in python?
My current code is shown below, but it does not return a complete array for both options. How do I create an output array with tanc() values?

```
def tanc(x):

    if x == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return np.tan(x)/x
```

want an output such as:
`array([ 1.0,  0.27323654e+00, -4.89610183e-17])`

Comment: Check out `np.where`.

Comment: @Mad Physicist i got an error that says "boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 7 but corresponding boolean dimension is 3"

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), and the `where` parameter to [`np.divide`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html) and [`np.tan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tan.html).

`np.where(cond, a, b)` gives an array where values from `a` are used for elements of `cond` that are truthy, and elements of `b` for the falsy elements of `cond`.

`np.divide` and `np.tan`'s `where` argument tells them to only do their operation at locations that are true in another array, and leave some the other elements uninitialized (so they could be anything, but it doesn't matter, because we're not going to use them here).

```
nonzero = x != 0 # we only care about places where x isn't 0
# Get tan, then divide by x, but only where x is not 0
nonzero_tan = np.tan(x, where=nonzero)
nonzero_tanc = np.divide(nonzero_tan, x, where=nonzero)
# Where x is not zero, use tan(x)/x, and use 1 everywhere else
tanc = np.where(nonzero, nonzero_tanc, 1)
```

---

As suggested by hpaulj in their comment, you can combine the last two steps by also using the `out` parameter of `np.divide` to define the default values of the output array:

```
nonzero = x != 0
nonzero_tan = np.tan(x, where=nonzero)
tanc = np.divide(nonzero_tan, x, out=np.ones_like(x), where=nonzero)
```

Comment: This is one of the first times I've seen `where` used correctly on SO. No computation errors and no duplicates work. Nice job

Comment: You can probably speed this up even further by using the `out` parameter.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You probably could, but unless speed is a special concern, there's no reason to.

Comment: Other times when I've explored using the `where` parameter, I found it works best with an `out` which defines the 'default' values (the non-where).  Without the `out` the `ufunc` starts with an `empty` array.  Here I think using an `np.ones_like(x)` in the `divide` would replace the last `where` statement.

Comment: @hpaulj That's a good point; I've added it as an addendum to my answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I got an error that says "boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 7 but corresponding boolean dimension is 3"

Answer (score 2):

Use a mask to encode your condition for each element:

```
mask = (x != 0)
```

You can apply numpy operations to the portions of the data that satisfy your condition:

```
output = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=float)
output[~mask] = 1
output[mask] = tan(x[mask]) / x[mask]
```

All together (with reduced redundant operations):

```
def tanc(x):
    output = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=float)
    output[~mask] = 1
    selected = x[mask]
    output[mask] = tan(selected) / selected
    return output
```

**Post Scriptum**

[@jirasaimok's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58228148/2988730) is, in my option, a more elegant (numpythonic if you will) way to accomplish the same thing: avoid more than one computation per element, and avoid zero division. I would suggest that their answer can be further enhanced by using the `out` keyword of `tan` and `divide` to avoid allocating and copying unnecessary temporary arrays:

```
def tanc(x):
    mask = (x != 0)
    output = np.tan(x, where=mask)
    np.divide(output, x, where=mask, out=output)
    output[~mask] = 1
    return output
```

Or better yet:

```
def tanc(x):
    mask = (x != 0)
    output = np.tan(x, where=mask, out=np.ones(x.shape, float))
    return np.divide(output, x, where=mask, out=output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
def tanc(x):
    return np.sinc(x/np.pi)/np.cos(x)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. That is a great simple solution that i didn't think of.

Answer (score -3):

```py
def tanc(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return np.tan(x)/x

def return_array(some_array):
    return np.array(list(map(tanc, some_array)))
```

Comment: This will be extremely inefficient. You're basically giving up all the power of numpy by doing this.

Comment: is there a map equivalent in numpy ?

Comment: With NumPy, you generally operate on entire arrays or their dimensions using [universal functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) or the other features provided by NumPy, such as [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) (especially [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)).

Comment: Numpy functions are already vectorized: basically, map is built into everything. Ufuncs also have accumulate and reduce built into them.

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!